# Java quiz game button is not outputting statement

Tags: java, swing, output, jbutton, jlabel

I'm making a Java quiz program where if you click on a question button it gives you a question to answer. You then answer the question in a JTextField and press the button "check" to check the answer. If the answer is right, there should be a label (lblOutcome) which states "Correct" or "Wrong". I tried my if statements for this part of the code (displaying "correct" when the answer is right), but when I run it, it doesn't output anything.

Here's my code for when you click on a question button (to get a question):

```
if(whichOne.equals("Math"))
        {
            txtAnswer.setText("");
            q1 = true;
            btnOne.setEnabled(false);
            lblQuestion.setText("What's 2 + 2?");
        }
```

Here's my code for when you click the "check" button:

```
if(whichOne.equals("Check") && txtAnswer.equals("4") && q1==true)
        {
            
            score = score +1;
            lblOutcome.setText("Correct");
            q1 = false;
            
            //more
        }
```

Comment: What did u try to do with the second statment whichOne.equals("Check") and why it needs to be equalled  with check ?

Comment: @Dren I put it so that when the button that's pressed is the "check" button, the label will indicate whether the answer that was put in the textfield is correct/incorrect

Answer (score 2):

To get the text from a **JTextField** (which inherits JTextComponent) you need to use the inherited **getText()** method:

```
txtAnswer.getText()
```

Knowing this, the condition for your `if` statement for the "check" button **actionPerformed** event event should be what?

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it to << if(whichOne.equals("Check")&& txtAnswer.getText().equals("answer") && q1==true) >> , and it works now! I'm so relieved thank you !

Comment: @gino it would be nice to upvote his answer.

Comment: @dren lol i tried to but something about accounts who are under 15 days old can’t do it or something ???